# Merging Cells in Bootstrap Table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I have troubles merging Cells in [Bootstrap Table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/)
I've found an example [here](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#methods/mergeCells.html).

But I don't want the merging executed by clicking a button, instead I want to merge automatically.

Here's my code:

```
<table id='ViewTable'
       data-toggle='table'
       data-url='func/json.php?id=1'
       data-class='table table-hover table-condensed'
       data-striped='true'
       data-show-header='false'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field='picture'></th>
        <th data-field='description'></th>
        <th data-field='value'></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ViewTable').bootstrapTable('mergeCells', {
                index: 0,
                field: 'picture',
                rowspan: 12
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Any suggetions?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a table and not a container, there you could add class col-xs-12

Comment: Yeah, I want to use a table...

Comment: Ok, why don't you put a div left of the table instead of joining all rows?

Comment: How do I align it to the left of the table?

Comment: Put the table and the div for the data inside another div. then you can probly set with css float left and right to position the 2 elements next to each other. You can also set the width of the parent div to 100% and the data div and table to 50%or whatever suits you, I think that's it

Comment: Do you understand what I mean? might also have to set display: inline-block; for table and inner div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `post-body.bs.table` event to do what you want:

```
var $table = $('#ViewTable');

$(function () {
    $table.on('post-body.bs.table', function () {
        $table.bootstrapTable('mergeCells', {
            index: 0,
            field: 'picture',
            rowspan: 12
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/1372/) example.